# Require.js and SPDY

Tags: requirejs, spdy

I know that doing many requests for different scripts is bad for performance, i.e. my script requires 30 dependecies, so require.js would make 31 request for that. I could make use of require optimizer and download bundles of scripts.

What if I use SPDY and still make those 31 request would the ability to multiplex the requests help me out and would not make difference performance wise?

Thank you

Comment: So did you make it at the end?

Comment: No, it was only a theoretical question because I would not want to do multiple request to get assets until major part of browsers support SPDY feature

Comment: I tried it today. It appears that files in SPDY are slightly faster that those in HTTP when the count is larger than 100. For 20 files, SPDY looks slower. I took down some notes here(but in Chinese), maybe some of them are helpful. http://blog.segmentfault.com/jiyinyiyong/1190000000471129

Answer (score 2):

When you use SPDY, the ability to multiplex requests will likely improve your performance.

The reason is that with plain HTTP, browsers can usually make only 6 requests concurrently (assuming all your 30 scripts will be downloaded from the same domain).
Then the browsers have to wait at least one network roundtrip before being able to perform the 7th request.
Depending on where your clients are with respect to your server, a network roundtrip can be in the 50ms to 500ms range, sometimes even more.

With SPDY, all 30 requests can be made at once thanks to multiplexing.

Furthermore, SPDY server that implement SPDY Push may be able to push the 30 secondary resources down to the client along with the initial request for the primary resource (usually, the HTML page).

[Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty) implements SPDY Push, and you can watch [this demo](http://webtide.intalio.com/2012/10/spdy-push-demo-from-javaone-2012/) to see the difference that SPDY Push make when you're requesting 20+ secondary resources associated to the primary resource.

You can find the Jetty SPDY documentation [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/spdy.html), and a [blog post](http://webtide.intalio.com/2012/06/spdy-we-push/) that shows how to configure SPDY Push in Jetty.

Comment: So basicly it would be ok to make 31 request to get all js files IF I use SPDY?

Comment: Could you give a example here? I setup a SPDY Nginx file server here, but found it is still slow. I may guess that, since the files are requested one by one by RequireJS, it may no be the same like normal HTML pages, which Chrome combines all requests into one. Is that possible?

Comment: A browser parsing a HTML page with 30 images in it does not have to stop parsing when it finds the first image. The delay between image requests is due to the parsing, not to the network.  Similarly, RequireJS can request *.js files in parallel without waiting for each one to be downloaded.  These are cases where SPDY helps thanks to multiplexing, especially if the number of images is large (say, more than 10). I use Jetty (I am one of its developers), cannot help much about Nginx.